# How to print out array of characters using a pointer to that array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In my code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define BLOCKSIZE 256;

int main()
{
char text[BLOCKSIZE];

char *new_line;
new_line=strcpy(text,"hello");

int i;
for(i=0;i<sizeof(text)/sizeof(char);i++)
{
printf("%c",*(new_line+i));
}

return 0;

}
```

I am trying to print the string "hello" on screen using a pointer which points to the address of the char array text. But in my code I get the string hello continued by some garbage values and then leads to core dumped. Can anyone show me the right way? Thanks
[image]

Comment: `char *ptr = text; while (*ptr) printf("%c",*ptr++);`  Your code is attempting to print 256 `char` of `"hello"` which is only 6 `char` long.  GTG

Comment: Thanks,What does while(*ptr) do ? What kind of condition is *ptr?

Comment: `*ptr` takes the pointer `ptr` and reads what it points to: some `char`.  The value of that `char` is tested in `while(*ptr)` for truth-ness (is it non-zero)?  So if the end of the string is not reached (the `'\0'`), the while loop continues.

Answer (score 1):

`for(i=0;i < sizeof(text)/sizeof(char);i++)`

The size of `text` is 256 bytes as you have allocated 256 bytes to it. `sizeof(text)/sizeof(char)` would return a value much greater than the size of "hello". That is why the loop is printing garbage values after "hello". You should use `i < strlen(text)` instead.

Comment: A much better way to write this code is suggested by chux in the comments section under your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing out all 256 characters of your `text` array.  You only want to iterate up to the length of the string, like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As well stated by [@tourniquet_grab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2881114/tourniquet-grab), code is printing beyond the end of `"Hello"`

Code copies `"Hello"` into the ample sized `text[]`, but only the first 6 `char` (up to and including the terminating null character `'\0'`).  The pointer returned by `strcpy()` is the address of the first `char` of `text`.  The remaining 250 `char` of `text` has not been initialized.  So the following prints `"Hello"`, a  `'\0'` and 250 pieces of junk.

```
  new_line = strcpy(text,"hello");
  for(i=0;i<sizeof(text)/sizeof(char);i++) {
    printf("%c",*(new_line+i));
  }
```

More sensible to print the *string* contents of `new_line` - only up to, but not including the terminating null character `'\0'`.  This method will change the pointer of new_line.

```
  new_line = strcpy(text,"hello"); 
  // Continue looping until \0 reached
  while (*new_line)  {
    printf("%c", *new_line++);
  }
```

---

Minor points:

`sizeof(char)` is *always* 1. Rarely useful to code that.  If anything, code `sizeof(text)/sizeof(text[0])`.

Rather than `printf("%c",*new_line++);`, could use `fputc(*new_line++, stdout)` or other 1 `char` functions like `putc()`